# How to create a datetime column from only week value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['WEEK'], unit='D')
data
Out[59]: 
    Unnamed: 0  WEEK    UNITS_x DOLLARS_x   UNITS_y DOLLARS_y   F       D   PR  date
0    0          1583    2.0      27.36       47       643.26    NONE    1   1   1974-05-03
1    1          1584    0.0      0.00        47       643.26    NONE    1   1   1974-05-04
2    2          1585    0.0      0.00        58       872.32    B       1   0   1974-05-05
3    3          1586    0.0      0.00        10       154.90    NONE    1   0   1974-05-06
4    4          1587    2.0      27.36       11       170.39    NONE    1   0   1974-05-07
```

I want to convert the WEEK column to dateline, and I tried:

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['WEEK'], unit='D')

data_2010 = data.loc[(data['WEEK'] >= 1583) & (data['WEEK'] <= 1634)]
ValueError: time data '15832010-1' does not match format '%V%G-%u' (match)
```

can anyone help me how to convert it correctly, for WEEK from 1583-1634 is year 2010, and for WEEK from 1635-1686 is year 2011, and for WEEK from 1687-1739 is year 2012, I tried to split the week into 2010 first, and convert it to date, but it does not work, thank you.

Comment: what is the week value supposed to represent? weeks since a specific date (epoch)? e.g. if a value of 1583 weeks (~30 years) should be year 2010, the epoch would be 1980

Answer (score 0):

Interesting issue.
I would probably start with a dictionary to define the weeks to dates.

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data["WEEK"]).dt.date
```

Is the correct way to approach this if you are working from date and datetime. Given you are using a (seemingly arbitrary) number for the week, you may be better off creating an exquation for this (as below).

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime((data["WEEK"]*7)).dt.date
```

Or whatever an appropriate equation might be (I'll leave that to you).

Comment: Hi, what does the start with a dictionary to define the weeks to dates mean, I tried the code above, but the year is still on 1974, thank you

Comment: Hi, what I mean is a list of value pairs. So when yoou get a value of '0' you know it means '6' for example. A dictionary can be used for this.
As I stated above though, an equation may be simplest for your use case.